# Pantalla negra Ubuntu Virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-server, grub

Tengo una máquina virtual de Ubuntu Server 20.04 con VirtualBox. Inicio la máquina virtual, me aparece el log de donde se está cargando.

Hasta ahí todo bien: me carga todo lo que he instalado en mi máquina virtual, pero después se me pone la pantalla en negro, con un cursor para escribir sin parpadear en la esquina superior izquierda.

Si funciona el servidor, porque me conecto con ssh y puedo hacer todo lo que hago, incluso desde otra máquina de la red local mediante ssh. El detalle ha de ser algo de la pantalla.

Lo que he intentado es reiniciar la máquina manteniendo presionado shift y encima de la primera opcion del grub al presionar **e**.

Luego busqué la linea que contiene ‘$vt_handoff’ (junto a ‘quiet splash…’), para borrar el valor ‘$vt_handoff’; pero no aparece la línea para borrarla. Entonces con ssh me conecté y con  sudo nano /etc/default/grub agregué las líneas

> GRUB_DEFAULT=0 
> GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
> GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
> GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
> GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset acpi_osi="Linux""
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
> GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX="auto"

y luego sudo update-grub pero aún no soluciono el problema, aquí adjunto el contenido de /etc/default/grub

> #If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
> #/boot/grub/grub.cfg.
> #For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
> #info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'
>
> GRUB_DEFAULT=0
> GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
> GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
> GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="maybe-ubiquity"
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
>
> GRUB_DEFAULT=0
> #GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
> GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
> GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
> GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset acpi_osi="Linux""
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
> GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX="auto"
>
> #Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
> #This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
> #the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
> #GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"
>
> #Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
> #GRUB_TERMINAL=console
>
> #The resolution used on graphical terminal
> #note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
> #you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
> #GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
>
> #Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
> #GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true
>
> #Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
> #GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
>
> #Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
> #GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"

[image: Adjunto imagen de la pantalla del grub, no hallé como convertirla a texto]
Adjunto imagen de la pantalla del grub, no hallé como convertirla a texto